# Android Wear app not visible in store (Internal test track)

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I have published my first wear app to Internal test track in Play Store. The app is dependent on mobile application and I used Multi APK to deploy both apk within a release.

I can see the mobile app in Google Play and search for it. On the watch I am unable to find my app in Google Play. The direct link (available from Opt-in URL) works fine and I am able to install my app.

Furthermore, when I install mobile app I do not receive any notification on my watch (see https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging):
*"On devices running Wear 2.0, when a user installs a phone app that has an associated watch app (either an embedded APK or an APK uploaded via the Play Console), the user gets a watch notification about the available watch app"*

Comment: Message from end of 2021. It is still not working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have your wear app searchable in the store you have to:

- deploy the app to OPEN channel (so internal channel won't work, alpha
  either, even if this is open alpha - tested)
- provide at least one
  graphics for wear (strange)

Comment: I couldn't deploy to beta channel either, even if it is open. Only production works

Comment: Thanks, this helps on Dec 7 2021.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Method to test apk in watch**

1. Install 'Wear Installer' app on watch & phone.
2. Turn on Developer Options in watch.(Settings->About->build number(press four times)).
3. Turn on Debug over Wifi.(Settings-> Developer Options-> Turn on Debug over Wifi)
4. Link to install from phone - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freepoc.wearinstaller&hl=en_IN&gl=US
5. Open the 'Wear Installer' app on watch, it will show you the IP Address.
6. Open the 'Wear Installer' app from phone and add the watch IP Address.
7. Select the watch apk in the phone in Downloads of 'Wear Installer'.
8. It will start connecting to watch & press 'Allow Debugging from this device' in watch.
9. Watch will be connected with phone.
10. Click install in 'Wear Installer' in phone.
11. Apk will get installed in watch.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like the sort of bug it is worth contacting Play Console support about. In the Play console on the "?" (help) icon there are various methods of doing this including email and live chat (depending on your country, language and time of day)

Comment: This is still not working. Why couldn't the Google Play team take a look at this issue and fix it?